# Where can I learn how to make a Javascript powered dropdown menu in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a Navigation Bar at top that has:

```
    <%= link_to content_tag(:li, "Watching me"), followers_user_path(current_user) %>

    <%= link_to content_tag(:li, "I'm Watching"), following_user_path(current_user) %>
```

And I'd like to create another link that has a javascript dropdown menu with these options as choices instead...

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a ton of options here, but I think the best is to use Twitter Bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html.

You'll have to install jQuery too.

Comment: twitter bootstrap really awesome !